# speedy unpacking of a list of list of tuples in Python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tuples

I have what is probably a trivial Python question, I have a list of lists of tuples in the following format:

```
lis1=[[(1,2),(3,4)],[(5,6),(7,8)]]
```

which I want to convery to a single list of tuples with *ideally* a space between the lists, like so:

```
lis2=[1,2,3,4, ,5,6,7,8]
```

or simply as a single list:

```
lis3=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

what would be the *fastest* way to achieve this?

Thanks!

### Edit

So far I have tried:

```
lis3=[w for w in term for term in lis1]
```

and a for loop

```
lis3=[]
for term in lis1:
    for w in term:
        lis3.append(w)
```

which works, but I am really looking for a single line implementation and to avoid the .append() function.

### Answer

you've mixed outer and inner loops in the list comprehension. Imagine you have a multiline code: for inner_list in outer_list: for item in inner_list: result.append(item) then the same as a list comprehension: result = [item for inner_list in outer_list for item in inner_list] note: the order of the loops is exactly the same. –  J.F. Sebastian

Comment: You cannot have a 'space' between elements. Perhaps use `None` instead.

Comment: Fast for the computer to execute, or fast for the programmer to write?

Comment: Thanks, I just found the duplicate question ([item for sublist in lis1 for item in sublist]). Feeling silly..

Comment: you've mixed outer and inner loops in the list comprehension. Imagine you have a multiline code: `for inner_list in outer_list: for item in inner_list: result.append(item)` then the same as a list comprehension: `result = [item for inner_list in outer_list for item in inner_list]` note: the order of the loops is exactly the same.

Comment: Thak you! I managed to get it working but @J.F.Sebastian you've explained it to me :)